# Render a string as a variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a site wide subnav, see code below:

```
= link_to "#{params[:controller].capitalize}", {:controller => "#{params[:controller]}", :action => "index"}
- if params[:action] != 'index'
  >
  = link_to "#{params[:action].capitalize.humanize}", {:controller => "#{params[:controller]}", :action => "#{params[:action]}"}
  >
  = "@#{params[:controller]}"
```

The last line renders:

> @products

as a string which I'd like to render as a variable.

Comment: what do you mean when you say you'd like to render it 'as a variable'?

Comment: do you have @products as variable in controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render the value of instance variable named `'@' + params[:controller]`, you can use [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) method:

```
= instance_variable_get("@#{params[:controller]}")
```